# Scraping URL links in a table

Tags: python, web-scraping, url

I have been able to scrape the other data without issues, also I can scrape the url links using the code below.

```
response2 = requests.get(url2)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response2.text, 'lxml')


for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print(link['href'])
```

However I now face two challenges:

1- I am only interested in the URL as highlighted for each line (the event link)

2- how do I use these links to scrape the data from each page in turn (the same as if I setup a new code for each of the links replacing the url of urlfix)

```
urlfix = 'https://www.rootsandrain.com/organiser21/uci/events/filters/dh/'
responsefix = requests.get(urlfix)
dffix = pd.read_html(responsefix.text)[0]

#remove times and other data
dffix.drop('Time', axis=1, inplace=True)  
dffix.drop('Time.1', axis=1, inplace=True)  
dffix.drop('Competitors', axis=1, inplace=True)  

#rename columns
dffix.rename(columns = {dffix.columns[3] : 'Win_M'}, inplace = True)
dffix.rename(columns = {dffix.columns[4] : 'Win_F'}, inplace = True)


#filter for event
dffix['Worldchamps']=dffix['Event'].str.contains(r'World Championships', na=True)
dffix['Worldcup']=dffix['Event'].str.contains(r'World Cup', na=True)
#this line for do no contain , | for two
dffix['Miscrace']=~dffix['Event'].str.contains(r'World Championships|World Cup', na=True)


with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):  # more options can be specified also
    print(dffix)
```

[Screenshot of the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToFBt.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** *For future questions - There should only be one issue per question to keep focus - Every other is predestined to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).*

Just to point in a direction, select your elements more specific and be aware you have to concat the `href` with an baseUrl.

Following `list comprehension` will create a list of urls you can use to iterate and fetch the detail tables - Used `css selectors` to select each row in the `tbody` of the table with id `T1` and concat the `href` of each first `<a>` in row with baseUrl:

```
['https://www.rootsandrain.com'+row.a['href'] for row in soup.select('#T1 tbody tr')]
```

*Keep in mind that there is also a paging, there are detail pages without results,... - If you stuck there ask a new question and please provide also expected output. Thanks*

#### Example

```
url = 'https://www.rootsandrain.com/organiser21/uci/events/filters/dh/'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

urlList = ['https://www.rootsandrain.com'+row.a['href'] for row in soup.select('#T1 tbody tr')]

data = []

for url in urlList:
    try:
        data.append(pd.read_html(url)[0])
    except:
        print(f'No tables found:{url}')

pd.concat(data)
```

#### Output

```
...
No tables found:https://www.rootsandrain.com/event9599/2022-jul-9-mercedes-benz-uci-world-cup-dh-4-lenzerheide/
No tables found:https://www.rootsandrain.com/event9598/2022-jun-11-mercedes-benz-uci-world-cup-dh-3-leogang/
No tables found:https://www.rootsandrain.com/event9597/2022-may-22-mercedes-benz-uci-world-cup-dh-2-fort-william/
...
```

| Unnamed: 0 | Pos⇧ | Bib | Name | Unnamed: 4 | Licence | YoB | Sponsors | km/h | sector1 + | sector2 + | sector3 + | sector4 + | sector5 = | Qualifier | km/h.1 | sector1 +.1 | sector2 +.1 | sector3 +.1 | sector4 +.1 | sector5 =.1 | Run 1 | Diff | sector3 = | sector3 =.1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| nan | 1st | 3 | Loïc BRUNI | nan | 1.00075e+10 | 1994 | Specialized Gravity | 57.781 | 28.973s1 | 1:08.4101 | 40.922s1 | 31.328s6 | 24.900s11 | 3:14.5331 | 59.062 | 28.697s1 | 1:08.8755 | 40.703s1 | 31.067s16 | 24.037s3 | 3:13.3791 | - | nan | nan |
| nan | 2nd | 7 | Troy BROSNAN | nan | 1.00073e+10 | 1993 | Canyon Collective Factory Team | 56.258 | 29.331s8 | 1:09.1763 | 42.676s6 | 30.488s2 | 24.493s2 | 3:16.1643 | 59.023 | 29.008s5 | 1:09.40313 | 41.363s8 | 30.121s2 | 23.905s2 | 3:13.8002 | 0.421s | nan | nan |
| nan | 3rd | 16 | Ángel SUÁREZ ALONSO | nan | 1.00088e+10 | 1995 | COMMENCAL 21 | 54.1939 | 30.077s26 | 1:18.27071 | 1:16.68773 | 2:00.79772 | 26.728s67 | 5:32.55972 | 58.067 | 28.991s4 | 1:09.2669 | 41.973s16 | 29.531s1 | 24.249s7 | 3:14.0103 | 0.631s | nan | nan |

Comment: thanks for the help.

The code only seems to pull the 2022 urls when i run it?

Comment: `urlList` contains all of them - take a look. Urls are only printed  cause it is an "pre-event" and so no information is available. for all the other it collects the results.

Comment: How to add the event name to the data that is scraped? for exampl in your table above add a column on the first location to state event , then the row has the event name (fromt he link it was scraped)?

Comment: New question up

Answer (score 1):

To get event link only use CSS selector `.future  td:nth-child(2) a`

```
for link in soup.select('.future  td:nth-child(2) a'):
    print(link['href'], link.text)
```