# Further table url link scraping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Using this awesome code I can scrape the majority of the data, however it seems like some of the url's may not scrape.  Also I need to be able to identify the data source in the future.  Therefore I have two question:

- how to program in a check that all links are identified and scraped?
- how to insert the url link as a new column so each row is identified?

  ```
    url = 'https://www.rootsandrain.com/organiser21/uci/events/filters/dh/'
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

    urlList = ['https://www.rootsandrain.com'+row.a['href'] for row in soup.select('#T1 tbody tr')]

    data = []

    for url in urlList:
        try:
            data.append(pd.read_html(url)[0])
        except:
            print(f'No tables found:{url}')

    pd.concat(data)
  ```

Original post

[Scraping URL links in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71568560/scraping-url-links-in-a-table/71569044?noredirect=1#comment126565727_71569044)

Answer (score 1):

A small adjustment to the `try/except` block, that writes the url and also the status of scraping:

```
    try:
        df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
        df['url'] = url
        df['scraped'] = True
        data.extend(df.to_dict(orient = 'records'))
    except:
        print(f'No tables found:{url}')
        data.append(dict(url=url, scraped=False))
```

##### Example

Limited to `for url in urlList[5:10]` to not iterate all of the links in this example, just kick the `[5:10]` to get all:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.rootsandrain.com/organiser21/uci/events/filters/dh/'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

urlList = ['https://www.rootsandrain.com'+row.a['href'] for row in soup.select('#T1 tbody tr')]

data = []

for url in urlList[5:10]:
    try:
        df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
        df['url'] = url
        df['scraped'] = True
        data.extend(df.to_dict(orient = 'records'))
    except:
        print(f'No tables found:{url}')
        data.append(dict(url=url, scraped=False))
        
pd.DataFrame(data)

#to get rid of all these NaN columns
#pd.DataFrame(data).dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

##### Output

| url | scraped | Pos⇧ | Bib | Name | Licence | YoB | Sponsors | km/h | sector1 + | sector2 + | sector3 + | sector4 + | sector5 = | Qualifier | km/h.1 | sector1 +.1 | sector2 +.1 | sector3 +.1 | sector4 +.1 | sector5 =.1 | Run 1 | Diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| https://www.rootsandrain.com/event9599/2022-jul-9-mercedes-benz-uci-world-cup-dh-4-lenzerheide/ | False | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| https://www.rootsandrain.com/event9598/2022-jun-11-mercedes-benz-uci-world-cup-dh-3-leogang/ | False | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| https://www.rootsandrain.com/event9597/2022-may-22-mercedes-benz-uci-world-cup-dh-2-fort-william/ | False | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| https://www.rootsandrain.com/event9607/2022-apr-23-dhi-masters-world-championships-22-villa-la-angostura/ | False | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| https://www.rootsandrain.com/event9596/2022-mar-27-mercedes-benz-uci-world-cup-dh-1-lourdes/ | True | 1st | 6 | Amaury PIERRON | 1.00088e+10 | 1996 | COMMENCAL - MUC-OFF BY RIDING | 62.211 | 45.680s5 | 32.179s3 | 36.880s2 | 27.636s5 | 28.399s8 | 2:50.7743 | 60.3411 | 44.269s1 | 33.091s23 | 36.159s1 | 26.774s2 | 27.418s1 | 2:47.7111 | - |
| https://www.rootsandrain.com/event9596/2022-mar-27-mercedes-benz-uci-world-cup-dh-1-lourdes/ | True | 2nd | 14 | Finn ILES | 1.00909e+10 | 1999 | Specialized Gravity | 60.072 | 44.915s3 | 32.242s5 | 37.407s5 | 27.636s5 | 28.254s3 | 2:50.4542 | 59.0821 | 44.924s2 | 31.474s3 | 37.175s4 | 26.781s3 | 28.204s6 | 2:48.5582 | 0.847s |
| https://www.rootsandrain.com/event9596/2022-mar-27-mercedes-benz-uci-world-cup-dh-1-lourdes/ | True | 3rd | 1 | Loïc BRUNI | 1.00075e+10 | 1994 | Specialized Gravity | 59.6027 | 45.080s4 | 31.429s1 | 37.254s4 | 27.164s2 | 28.344s6 | 2:49.2711 | 58.8225 | 45.023s4 | 31.653s6 | 37.112s3 | 27.172s5 | 27.837s3 | 2:48.7973 | 1.086s |
| https://www.rootsandrain.com/event9596/2022-mar-27-mercedes-benz-uci-world-cup-dh-1-lourdes/ | True | 4th | 8 | Benoit COULANGES | 1.00082e+10 | 1994 | Dorval AM Commencal | 60.671 | 46.785s15 | 31.773s2 | 36.688s1 | 27.496s3 | 28.348s7 | 2:51.0905 | 59.0821 | 45.302s7 | 31.591s5 | 37.745s9 | 26.711s1 | 27.828s2 | 2:49.1774 | 1.466s |
| https://www.rootsandrain.com/event9596/2022-mar-27-mercedes-benz-uci-world-cup-dh-1-lourdes/ | True | 5th | 17 | Luca SHAW | 1.00088e+10 | 1996 | Canyon Collective Factory Team | 59.0836 | 46.267s7 | 32.952s14 | 38.067s10 | 28.504s17 | 28.453s9 | 2:54.24310 | 61.223 | 45.223s6 | 31.572s4 | 37.436s7 | 27.629s12 | 28.282s10 | 2:50.1425 | 2.431s |
| https://www.rootsandrain.com/event9596/2022-mar-27-mercedes-benz-uci-world-cup-dh-1-lourdes/ | True | 6th | 9 | Danny HART (elt) | 1.00055e+10 | 1991 | CUBE FACTORY RACING | 59.8722 | 47.041s22 | 32.715s8 | 37.246s3 | 28.000s11 | 28.301s4 | 2:53.3037 | 60.0714 | 46.511s21 | 31.868s7 | 36.600s2 | 27.391s10 | 28.036s4 | 2:50.4066 | 2.695s |